# What are the practical advantages to a SSD+HDD setup laptop?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I am trying to choose between a laptop with only HDD and one with 120GB SSD + 500GB HDD. I know that SSD-s are faster, of course. But, what are the practical, user-side advantages of this. **Which operations on a computer are swifter?**

For example, here are several use cases.

1. Check out the linux kernel to the HDD (OS is on the SSD). Configure and build it.
2. Install Neverwinter Nights 2 on the SSD. Play.
3. Download a DVD-quality movie to the HDD. Play it.
4. Lounch Eclipse IDE. Open some files, compile another project at the same time (working directory on HDD).
5. Open a 5000 page PDF (on the HDD). Scroll with the slider 1111 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSD does not have any appreciable seek time. 
This means that operations that open lots of files or read a lot of data will occur faster.

Operations that don't really require a lot of data, e.g. fixed data rate like music and movies, will probably be unaffected.

So in your cases above, I don't expect much improvement overall.

I would expect significant improvements if your moved your source trees to the SSD (case 1 and 4). The others: I don't expect much improvement unless your HDD is seriously fragmented.

Comment: Also - lots of people make a big deal out of the much faster boot times of an SSD (5 seconds as opposed to 30).

Comment: I decided I do not need an SSD. It would have been 30% if the price of the laptop.